# Span not wrapping inside div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to highlight textarea words by putting a `div` behind my field and copying over the values.

```
$("div").html($("textarea").text()
   .replace("bad-word", "<span style='background-color: red'>bad-word</span>"))
```

I mocked it up and it works fine in Chrome. But in IE it seems that `span`s won't jump to the next line of the `div`, when the word is too big to fit on that row. Instead it seems to force a break-word sort of effect - which the `textarea` doesn't do, so the words don't align anymore. Tested in IE8 + 9.

[image: IE 9 screenshot]
*Screenshot, code result in IE 9*

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zt2Az/15/). try adding a letter at the start of the textarea and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Wooow you're writing javascript but you have a lack of knowledge on HTML markup. `<div>` elements really like to have an `</div>`

Comment: Ironically using bad HTML trying to detect bad language...

Comment: IE, dear IE... why are you so buggy?

Comment: @VukašinManojlović it's not IE, all other browsers are! ;D

Comment: @roXon I like that fairytale... ;)

Comment: If a vertical scrollbar is present in the textarea but not in the div, the effective width of the textarea will be less than the width of the div. The width of the scrollbar and whether it appears (enabled or disabled) varies from browser to browser and from platform to platform.

Answer (score 0):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zt2Az/25/)**

```
$("#g1").val("This is me talking about pizza, cheese and also other pizza too hello! how are you?");

$("#g1").keyup(function(e) {
    keyUp(this);
})

function keyUp( el ) {
    var txtArea = $(el);
    var txtAVal = txtArea .val();
    txtAVal = txtAVal.replace(/pizza/gi, "<span style='background:red'>pizza</span>");
    $("#g2").html(txtAVal );
}
```